# Continuous integration strategy for snapshot dependencies (with Jenkins)

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, jenkins

While setting up a Jenkins CI system for the first time, I wonder how to deal with snapshot dependencies and the local Maven repository.

We have an artifact X with dependency Y. Jenkins is configured to build X everytime Y has a commit.

**Strategy A (workspace Maven repository):**
The local Maven repository is configured to be "local to the workspace". This means that every built job has its own repository. A commit of Y does trigger the build (a "mvn clean install"), but since the repositories of build X and Y are isolated, X uses the last *deployed* version of Y, not the last commit.
Using this strategy seems useful to detect if all dependencies are also deployed, but it doesn't detect integration issues (broken Y commit breaks X).

**Strategy B (common Maven repository):**
Jenkins uses a common local Maven repository. A commit of a (broken) Y snapshot triggers the build of X which uses the current Y snapshot, and integration issues are detected. The drawback is, that this doesn't detect if all build dependencies are deployed to the central snapshot repository (because the CI system does have them all installed in the local repository).

Is there a strategy that combines both advantages of A and B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We ended up using a *Strategy C* for this:

**Strategy C (let Jenkins deploy):**
Every job has its local repository local to the workspace like in strategy A. But instead of the default "clean install" goal, Jenkins is configured to do a "-U clean deploy" on every job. So if Y is broken and commited, Jenkins will build it and deploy it to the central snapshot repository. Jenkins detects the build of the dependency Y and builds X with *the latest Y snapshot*.
Useful for this strategy is - at least with Maven 3 - to run a automatic cleanup job on the central snapshot repository, since there will be a lot of timestamped snapshots.